Basis for the vector subspace $W\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that $\mathbf{w}\in W$ implies $A\mathbf{w}\in W$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with real entries. Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for every $\textbf{w}$ in $W$, $A\mathbf{w}$ is also in $W$. Suppose $A$ is diagonalisable and has exactly three distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,$ and $\lambda_3$. Show that $W$ has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

My thought:
So, it is clear that the corresponding eigenvectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2$ and $\mathbf{v}_3$ are linearly independent.
On the other hand, we know that $A$ has a rank 3.
If we can show that $\dim W=\text{rank} A=3$, and the three eigenvectors belong to $W$, then the problem can be solved flawlessly.
My problem:

The three eigenvectors are not necessarily belong to $W$. Say, $W$ can be simply $\{\textbf{0}\}$!
How is the dimension of $W$ and the rank of $A$ interrelated?

Perhaps my progress is totally off course. I am nearly clueless on this question.
Thanks for any answers in advance.

Having exactly three eigenvalues does not mean $n=3$, so you cannot conclude rank $A=3$, on the other hand, those eigenvalues can be $0$, which means it cannot be full rank also!

@hft1 Sorry but I can’t see how is that theorem related. Could you please elaborate a bit?

@hff1 Now I see it. My question is somehow duplicated that question. Thanks for telling me that.

@Zuka it’s not important


It is not beacause $A$ has exactly $3$ eigenvalues that $A$ does necessary have $\text{rank}(A) = 3$. Consider as a counterexample :
\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2  & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Then $A$ has exactly $3$ eigenvalues and $\text{rank}(A) = 4$.

The dimension of $W$ and the rank of $A$ are not interrelated. With diagonal matrix it is easy to construct for any $d,r \leq n$, $A \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\text{rank}(A) = r$ and $\text{dim}(W) = d$.

To solve your problem you have to consider the restriction of $A$ to $W$ as an endomorphism on $W$ ($A \in \mathcal{L}(W)$) and to show that this endomorphism is diagonalisable.



Once we show that $\sigma(A|_W)\subseteq \sigma(A)$, your desired result follows easily as:
$$A(w_{\lambda}) = A|_W(w_{\lambda}) = \lambda w_{\lambda}$$
shows eigenvectors for $A|_W$ are eigenvectors for $A$.

The following was inspired by Arturo's proof, as suggested by hff1 above.
Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we may write $V = W\oplus W^{\perp}$ with a joint basis $B$ making the matrix representation block diagonal (applying "$AW\subseteq W$"):
$$[A]_B = \begin{bmatrix}A_W && *\\ 0 && A_{W^{\perp}}\end{bmatrix}.$$
From here, it is clear that the characteristic polynomial for $A|_W$:
$$P_W(x) := det(A_W - xI_k)$$
divides that of $A$'s (since $[A]_B$ is block triangular, it is just a product of the two determinants -- I labeled $A_{W^{\perp}}$ the lower block, but we don't know if the image of the rest of the basis vectors stays in $W^{\perp}$ yet, so there is a $*$ for the remaining block).
Hence we have the spectral containment. 
I suppose we require $A$ to be diagonalizable to ensure the basis doesn't need any generalized eigenvectors that might change the proof. $\square$
